# How to convert 2D list to 1D list with Streams?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I've tried this code (`list` is `ArrayList<List<Integer>>`):

```
list.stream().flatMap(Stream::of).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but it doesn't do anything; the list is still a 2D list. How can I convert this 2D list to a 1D list?

Comment: Use `flatMap(stream -> stream)` instead.

Comment: That worked. `.flatMap(l -> l.stream())`. Why does that work, but `Stream::of` doesn't?

Comment: `Stream.of` _adds_ a dimension.

Comment: @GusChambers you can replace `.flatMap(l -> l.stream()`with `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` if you want to retain the method reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reason being that you're still receiving a list of lists is because when you apply [`Stream::of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-) it's returning a new stream of the existing ones.

That is when you perform [`Stream::of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-) it's like having `{{{1,2}}, {{3,4}}, {{5,6}}}` then when you perform [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) it's like doing this:

```
{{{1,2}}, {{3,4}}, {{5,6}}} -> flatMap -> {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}}
// result after flatMap removes the stream of streams of streams to stream of streams
```

rather you can use `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` to take a stream of streams such as:

```
{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}}
```

and turn it into:

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Therefore, you can change your current solution to:

```
List<Integer> result = list.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is:

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 2), Arrays.asList(3, 4));
List<Integer> faltList = listOfLists.
        stream().flatMap(s -> s.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(faltList);
```

Answer:
`[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `x.stream()` in your `flatMap`. Something like,

```
ArrayList<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Arrays.asList((Integer) 1, 2, 3));
list.add(Arrays.asList((Integer) 4, 5, 6));
List<Integer> merged = list.stream().flatMap(x -> x.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(merged);
```

Which outputs (like I think you wanted)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```